# SQL : For each Col1 group, return the Col2 value that has the Max(Col3)

Tags: sql

How can I select like this?

```
SELECT C1, C2, MAX(C3)
  FROM Table
  GROUP BY C1
```

Given

### C1  C2  C3

```
1  A  10
1  B  20
1  C  30
2  A  70
2  B  60
2  C  50
```

I would like to return:

### C1  C2  C3

```
1  C  30
2  A  70
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional aggregation is the first thing that comes to mind.  This should work in almost any database, because it uses standard SQL features:

```
select col1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then col2 end) as col2,
       max(col3) as col3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col3 desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by col1;
```

A similar method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col3 = (select max(t2.col3) from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col1);
```

This, in fact, should have better performance particularly with an index on `(col1, col3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of your query.

```
select c1,
       max(case when section = 1 then c2 end) as c2,
       max(c3) as c3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by c1 order by c3 desc) as section
      from TableName t
     ) t
group by c1
```